# Want to extract digits before decimal and after decimal as string in spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a number like this **000123.00** (lets call it myvar)

I want to use **SPARK SQL** to get following two results

1. *000123* (Digits before decimal point)
2. *2* (Count of digits after decimal point)

Note: I want the solution in a single SELECT statement.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: you can use split to get the two strings https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#split

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the number to string and use [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) to get both left and right side of decimal point, and then use [char_length function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#char_length) to retrieve the number of digits after decimal point.